# Exporting a variable inside a function with module.exports to be referred to in another file

Tags: ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

I am trying to find a solution for this, but no matter how much I read about ES6 destructuring and global variables, I still can't manage to solve this.

So, I am using sequelize to handle my MySQL database and it has been working perfectly, until I modified my database.js file and implemented "postgres" into it because i wanted to the add the (CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS..) syntax to my database.js, since it turned out not to be so straight forward and easy to do with sequelize. Now, the main problem is that after I modified the database.js file, I am not able to refer / extract the "sequelize" variable anymore since it is now scoped inside of a function that inside of another function.. I just need to find a way to extract this variable and be able to destructure it so I can send it with module.exports and be able to use it in my other users.js file (which has my users database model).

> This is my **database.js** file (all my database configurations are here)

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const pg = require('pg');

   function initialize(callback) {
    var dbName = 'onlinemarket',
        username = 'root',
        password = 'root',
        host = '127.0.0.1'
 
    var sequelize= ''; // in order to make it a global variable
    var conStringPri = 'postgres://' + username + ':' + password + '@' + host + '/postgres';
    var conStringPost = 'postgres://' + username + ':' + password + '@' + host + '/' + dbName;

    // connect to postgres db
    pg.connect(conStringPri, function(err, client, done) { 
        // create the db and ignore any errors, for example if it already exists.
        client.query('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS onlinemarket', function (err) {
              if (err) throw err;
              client.query('USE onlinemarket', function (err) {
                  if (err) throw err;
                          client.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users('
                          + 'ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,'
                          + 'username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,'
                          + 'password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,'
                          + 'first_name VARCHAR(255),'
                          + 'last_name VARCHAR(255),'
                          + 'PRIMARY KEY(ID),'
                          +  ');', function (err) {
                              if (err) throw err;
                          client.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts('
                          + 'ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,'
                          + 'title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,'
                          + 'description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,'
                          + 'category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,'
                          + 'city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,'
                          + 'country VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,'
                          + 'images VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,'
                          + 'price DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,'
                          + 'postDate DATE NOT NULL,'
                          + 'deliveryType VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,'
                          + 'sellerName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,'
                          + 'mobile VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,'
                          + 'PRIMARY KEY(ID),'
                          +  ');', function (err) {
                              if (err) throw err;
                      });
                  });
              });
            });
          }, function(err) {
            //db should exist now, initializing Sequelize after that
            sequelize = new Sequelize(conStringPost); //this is the variable which i need to get

            callback(sequelize);
            client.end(); // close the connection

            sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
              console.log('Database connection has been established successfully.');
            }).catch(err => {
              console.error('Unable to connect to the database: ' + err);
            });
    });
}

module.exports =  { sequelize };
```

This is the users.js file where I create the user model and as you can see at the top of the file trying to import / require the destructured "sequelize" variable in order to get the 'sequelize.define()' working. As long as I dont properly extract and export the sequelize variable, the console will keep giving me "sequelize is not defined"

> This is my **users.js** file

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../database').sequelize;

//The app needs to understand "sequelize.define"
module.exports = sequelize.define(
    'users',
    {
        ID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        username: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        first_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        last_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: false
    }
);
```

It was perfectly working before i did the modifications to it (as result of adding "postgres").
Here is my old **database.js** file before the modifications when I only used sequelize and it exported the variable smoothly to be referred to in the **users.js** file.

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = {} 

const sequelize = new Sequelize("onlinemarket", "root", "root", {
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    dialect: "mysql"
})

sequelize.authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Database connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database: ' + err);
  });


  db.sequelize = sequelize;
  db.Sequelize = sequelize; 

  module.exports = db;
```